# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.login.profile')

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView, Image, Card, Button, TouchableOpacity, AsyncStorage, 
ImageBackground } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import styles from './Styles/LoginScreenStyle';
import { View } from 'react-native-animatable';
import { Images } from '../Themes';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginActions from '../Redux/LoginRedux';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';



class LoginScreen extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoggedin: false,
      showPass: true,
      press: false,
      email: "",
      password: "",
      loginFailed: false,
      profile:  "",
      authMode: 'login',
    }
  }

  showPass = () => {
    if (this.state.press == false) {
      this.setState({ showPass: false, press: true})
    } else {
      this.setState({ showPass: true, press: false})
    }
  }

  handlePress = () => {
    console.log("ok")
    this.props.loginRequest(this.state.password,this.state.email)
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

  }

  handleSignUp = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate({routeName: 'SignUpScreen'})
  }


  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props.isLoggedin) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'UserScreen' });
    }

  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {



    if (newProps.isLoggedin) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'UserScreen' })
    }
    if (newProps.loginFailed) {
      this.setState({ isLoggedin: false })
    }
  }

  cheatButton = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate({routeName: 'UserScreen'})
  }


  render () {
    return (
<ImageBackground source={Images.loginbackground} style={styles.backgroundContainer} >
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
          <ScrollView style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView>
              <View>
                {/* <Header title='Login Screen' /> */}
              </View>

              <Image style={styles.logo} source={Images.ieuLogo} />
              <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.subtitleText}>Please Login Before Start</Text>
                <View>
                  <Icon name={'ios-person'} size={28} color={'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'} style={styles.inputIcon} />
                  <TextInput style={styles.textInput} underlineColorAndroid='transparent' placeholderTextColor={'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'} onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })} placeholder="Please enter your e-mail" ></TextInput>
                </View>
                <View>
                  <Icon name={'ios-lock'} size={28} color={'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'} style={styles.inputIcon} />
                  <TextInput secureTextEntry={this.state.showPass} style={styles.textInput} underlineColorAndroid='transparent' placeholderTextColor={'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'} onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })} placeholder="Please enter your password" ></TextInput>
                  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnEye}
                    onPress={this.showPass.bind(this)}>
                    <Icon name={this.state.press == false ? 'ios-eye' : 'ios-eye-off'} size={26} color={'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'} />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                < TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.handlePress()} style={styles.loginButton}>
                  <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>
                    LOGIN
           </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity> 
                < TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.cheatButton()} style={styles.loginButton}>
                  <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>
                    CHEAT
           </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                < TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.handleSignUp()} style={styles.loginButton}>
                  <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>
                    SIGN UP
           </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Image style={styles.logo1} source={Images.top_logo} />
              </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </ImageBackground>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    profile: state.login.profile,
    isLoggedin: state.login.isLoggedin,
    loginFailed: state.login.loginFailed,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loginRequest: (email, password) =>
      dispatch(LoginActions.loginRequest(email ,password))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen)
```

--------------------- Ignite Doctor -------------------------------

```
System
platform win32
arch x64
cpu 8 cores Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
directory SE330PROJECTLAST C:\Users\ogeda\Desktop\SE330PROJECTLAST

JavaScript
node 13.12.0 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
npm 6.14.5 C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
yarn 1.22.4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD

Ignite
ignite-cli 3.5.1 C:\Users\ogeda\AppData\Roaming\npm\ignite.CMD
ignite src build C:\Users\ogeda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ignite-cli\build
createdWith 3.5.1

boilerplate ignite-andross

examples classic

navigation react-navigation

askToOverwrite true

generators {"component":"ignite-andross","container":"ignite-andross","list":"ignite-andross","redux":"ignite-andross","saga":"ignite-andross","screen":"ignite-andross","listview":"ignite-andross"}

boilerplateVersion 4.2.0

Android
java - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.EXE
android home - C:\Users\ogeda\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Full version of bug report.---------

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.login.profile') This error is located at: in NavigationContainer (at create-redux-container.js:93) in NavigatorReduxWrapper (at ReduxNavigation.js:38) in ReduxNavigation (created by Context.Consumer) in Connect(ReduxNavigation) (at RootContainer.js:23) in RCTView (at RootContainer.js:21) in RootContainer (created by Context.Consumer) in Connect(RootContainer) (at App.js:24) in Provider (at App.js:23) in App in RCTView in Unknown (at renderApplication.js:40) in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101) in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119) in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

```
    package.json file ---------------------

{
        "name": "SE330PROJECTLAST",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "private": true,
        "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "standard --verbose | snazzy",
        "clean": "rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && watchman watch-del-all && npm cache clean --force",
        "clean:android": "cd android/ && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android",
        "newclear": "rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf ios/build && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean --force && npm i",
        "test:watch": "jest --watch",
        "updateSnapshot": "jest --updateSnapshot",
        "coverage": "jest --coverage && open coverage/lcov-report/index.html || xdg-open coverage/lcov-report/index.html",
        "android:build": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
        "android:install": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && ./gradlew installRelease",
        "android:hockeyapp": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && puck -submit=auto app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk",
        "android:devices": "$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb devices",
        "android:logcat": "$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb logcat :S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V",
        "android:shake": "$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb devices | grep '\t' | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/\s//g' | xargs -I {} $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb -s {} shell input keyevent 82",
        "storybook": "storybook start -p 7007",
        "lintdiff": "git diff --name-only --cached --relative | grep '\.js$' | xargs standard | snazzy",
        "fixcode": "standard --fix",
        "git-hook": "npm run lint -s && npm run test -s"
        },
        "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.0.1",
        "apisauce": "^1.1.1",
        "format-json": "^1.0.3",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "prop-types": "15.7.2",
        "querystringify": "^2.1.1",
        "ramda": "^0.27.0",
        "ramdasauce": "^2.1.3",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-native": "0.61.4",
        "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
        "react-native-config": "^0.12.0",
        "react-native-device-info": "1.6.1",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
        "react-native-i18n": "2.0.14",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^1.0.2",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "6.1.0",
        "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
        "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.13",
        "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^4.0.1",
        "react-navigation-stack": "^2.5.1",
        "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.8.13",
        "react-redux": "6.0.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.4",
        "redux-persist": "5.10.0",
        "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
        "reduxsauce": "^1.1.1",
        "seamless-immutable": "^7.1.4"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.2",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "5.0.11",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "5.0.11",
        "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^4.1.11",
        "@storybook/addons": "^4.1.11",
        "@storybook/channels": "^4.1.11",
        "@storybook/react-native": "^4.1.11",
        "babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "eslint": "^6.6.0",
        "ignite-andross": "^4.2.0",
        "ignite-animatable": "1.0.2",
        "ignite-dev-screens": "2.4.5",
        "ignite-i18n": "1.2.0",
        "ignite-redux-persist": "1.1.2",
        "ignite-standard": "1.0.0",
        "ignite-vector-icons": "1.1.1",
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.57.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
        "reactotron-react-native": "^4.0.2",
        "reactotron-redux": "^3.1.2",
        "reactotron-redux-saga": "^4.2.2",
        "snazzy": "^8.0.0",
        "standard": "10.0.2"
        },
        "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "testMatch": [
        "/Tests/**/.js",
        "**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
        ],
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/",
        "/Tests/Setup.js"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
        },
        "transform": {
        "^.+\.(js)$": "/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
        },
        "setupFiles": [
        "/Tests/Setup"
        ]
        },
        "config": {},
        "standard": {
        "parser": "babel-eslint",
        "globals": [
        "describe",
        "test",
        "jest",
        "expect",
        "fetch",
        "navigator",
        "DEV",
        "XMLHttpRequest",
        "FormData",
        "React$Element"
        ]
        }
        }
```

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I have developed an application for my internship like a year ago and it was working without any problem.Now I'm trying to write some code similar and creating something difference in the same structure using Ignite but I got an error. Please help me. **The inside of mapStateToProps function causing the problem I guess.**

Comment: It was caught by CharcoalHQ

Comment: What is the initial state of `login` in the store? I image it's undefined; try using some initial state like `{}` instead.